# Move from the rotating frame of reference to the lab frame for a periodic function

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, manipulate, animation, rotation

I have a plot in the rotating frame of reference which moves with some constant rate, S.

I want to convert this back into the lab frame by using some substitution of the form

*xAxisPositionLab = xAxisPositionRot + rotationRate* * *time.*

My functions are of this form

```
S=0.3;
rotFrameSin = Table[Sin[2*Pi*x/100 + S t], {x, 0, 100}];
labFrameSin = Table[Sin[2*Pi*x/100], {x, 0, 100}];
```

which produce lists of length 101.

Over time they behave in this way

```
ListAnimate[Table[ListLinePlot[rotFrameSin], {t, 0, 10, 0.1}]]
ListAnimate[Table[ListLinePlot[labFrameSin], {t, 0, 10, 0.1}]]
```

Is there any way to shift the plot in the rotating frame (`rotFrameSin`) along the x-axis the appropriate amount so that it is identical to the plot in the lab frame (`labFrameSin`) at each point in time?

I was thinking that using `Mod` or `RotateLeft` or even some sort of interpolation may work but I have not found any solutions yet.

Any help/tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for, is your X an angle?

Comment: I've edited the post so hopefully that clears things up. What I'm asking is basically can I move the plot in the rotating frame (`rotFrameSin`) along the x-axis so that it matches the lab frame plot (`labframeSin`) exactly at each time.

Comment: Why do you need ListAnimate for the lab frame at all? And do you want to have the frame of the plot, i.e. the background, the "thing" with the tick marks movable?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, I think the code below does the equivalent. You basically want to alter the x-values to account for the phase shift in `rotFrameSin` relative to `labFrameSin`, such that you can plot both on different x-values but the "shape" is the same?

I've avoided `ListAnimate` as I am not all that familiar with that function. You can alter `phase` to any value and the plots should keep looking the same with a shifted x. This is equivalent to your animation cycling over time.

Hopefully I have interpreted your question correctly.

Plus first time I have posted an answer ever, so hopefully the formatting etc. is ok.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(* Time on the x-axis *)
timeStep = 0.001;
maxTime = 1;
x = Range[0, maxTime, timeStep];
numTimeSteps = Dimensions[x];

(* Properties of the sine wave *)
cyclesPerSecond = 2;
freq = cyclesPerSecond/maxTime;
angFreq = 2*Pi*freq;
phase = Pi;

(* New x values to ensure alignment *)
shifter = phase/(angFreq*cyclesPerSecond)*cyclesPerSecond;
xp = x - shifter;

(* Plot *)
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{x, Sin[angFreq*x + phase]}], 
 PlotRange -> {{Min[x], Max[x]}, {-1, 1}},
 PlotLabel -> "rotFrameSin", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Time (secs)", "Amplitude"}, Frame -> True]

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{x, Sin[angFreq*x]}], 
 PlotRange -> {{Min[x], Max[x]}, {-1, 1}},
 PlotLabel -> "labFrameSin", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Time (secs)", "Amplitude"}, Frame -> True]

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xp, Sin[angFreq*xp + phase]}], 
 PlotRange -> {{Min[xp], Max[xp]}, {-1, 1}},
 PlotLabel -> "rotFrameSin (shited in x to match labFrameSin)", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Time (secs)", "Amplitude"}, Frame -> True]
```

Comment: Oh, also, this will continually add to the x-axis with the phase variable incrementing. As the plot is periodic, you could use ```Mod``` to shift the x-axis "back and forth" minimally to maintain the "shape". I was not sure what you wanted.